# In ARM Processor, How to determine if a shift is right or left shift?

Tags: c, arm

I am working on a software-based implementation of ARM processor in C. 
Given an ARM data processing instruction:

```
instruction = 0xE3A01808;               1110 0 0 1 1101 0 0000 0001 1000 00001000
```

Which translates to: `MOV r0,#8`; shifted by 8 bits.
How to check whether the 8 bit shift is right or left shift?

Comment: What do you mean by `MOV r0,#8` shifted by 8 bits ? Are you talking about `MOV` instructions or about bit shift instructions ? It's two different things.

Comment: it is a `MOV` instruction but before moving the immediate value to the register 0, it should go through barrel shiftier and shifted by 8 places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ARM 12-bit modified immediate constants, there is no *shift*, in any direction - it's a *rotation*, specifically, <7:0> rotated right by 2*<11:8>. Thus the encoding `0x808` represents 8 ROR (2*8), meaning `0xE3A01808` disassembles to `mov, r1, #0x80000`.

(Note that the canonical encoding of a modified immediate constant is the one with the smallest rotation, so `mov, r1, #0x80000` would *assemble* to `0xE3A01702`, i.e. 2 ROR 14, rather than 8 ROR 16<sup>1</sup>).

As for implementing bitwise rotation in C, to solve that there's either compiler intrinsics or the standard shift-part-in-each-direction idiom `x>>n | x<<(32-n)`.

---

[1] To get a specific encoding, UAL assembly allows an immediate syntax with the constant and rotation specified separately, i.e. `mov r1, #8, 16`. For full detail, this is all spelled out in [the ARM ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html) (section A5.2.4 in the v7 issue C I have here) - essentially, the choice of encodings permits a little funny business with flags in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're referring to, but here's some documentation that seems relevant:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0040d/ch05s05s01.html

The 'WITHDRAWN' pasted over the docs doesn't inspire much confidence.

It would seem to suggest a rotate right.  Which plays with how I remember the barrel shifter being addressed on arm more generally (There's a ROR operation for instance, see http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/barrel-shifter.html)

Comment: I know what right or left shit is but my problem is that i dont know how to do it in C. can any tell me if the shift in the instruction i have given is right or left?